# Connecting to MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB on mLab using by

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./modules/User');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds020168.mlab.com:20168/test_database');
```

I´ve stored this code in a file called test.js. Now, when I run the command

```
node test.js
```

it outputs the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I haven't set up an Express application, my projects just comprises of this test.js file and a package.json file with the required dependecies added and installed. Additionally, I've created a User model that is also imported into test.js.

Can someone explain to a beginner what else is required to successfully establish a connection and why the above code doesn't suffice? Besides, what does the error message tell me?

Comment: The error message tells you Node is failing to load a module (either mongoose or User), check you have mongoose in your node directories and that User is pathed correctly

Comment: Could you please post the code of `User` module?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change < dbuser> and < dbpassword> to yours?

Correct approach is:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ds020168.mlab.com:20168/test_database');
```

And NOT

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@ds020168.mlab.com:20168/test_database');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a syntax error in the User module and node.js can not import it.